# Make the robot stop if it finds an obstacle in front

Tags: navigation, ros2, nav2, avoid-obstacle

I am using the navigation stack (nav2) without problems, but I would like to understand how I can make the robot stop from its path if it finds a dynamic obstacle in front of it (at a minimum distance of n metres)?

Is there a demo or tutorial to take inspiration from?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CollisionMonitor package inside the Nav2 Stack.

Here is a tutorial: [Using Collision Monitor](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/using_collision_monitor.html#using-collision-monitor) and here are the sources [Github](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/main/nav2_collision_monitor)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* XXX. Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. See [answer] for more info.